# loading images from private dropbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, loading, private

I am dealing with sensitive images which have high value to my customer in a javascript application on Google Glass. Is there a way I can access them through javascript if I put them in - for example - a private dropbox? Is there any other way I can access/store images in javascript if they can't be hosted on the internet publicly and/or stored on the device?

Thanks!
Marc

Comment: I think you mean 'sensitive' (delicate or private) rather than 'sensible' (not silly).

Comment: oha yeah sorry haha that was my german that came through

Comment: Dropbox has an API and a JS SDK to access it, if that’s what you’re asking. Not sure though if that’s the easiest way to implement it – storing them on your own server, protected by a “common” login system might be easier than dealing with an external API (depends on how much experience you have with such things).